# Undefined reference to `g_ascii_strcasecmp'

Tags: c

I can compile with this line:

```
#include <glib.h>
```

But when I add this line:

```
GTree* t = g_tree_new((GCompareFunc)g_ascii_strcasecmp);
```

I'm getting this error:

```
 gcc cli.c -g -Wall -O0 -o httpget `pkg-config --cflags glib-2.0`

/s/cli.c:215: undefined reference to `g_ascii_strcasecmp'
/s/cli.c:215: undefined reference to `g_tree_new'
```

What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're forgetting to link with `glib`:

```
gcc `pkg-config --cflags glib-2.0` -g -Wall -O0 -o httpget cli.c `pkg-config --libs glib-2.0`
```

Or better, separate compilation and linking:

```
gcc `pkg-config --cflags glib-2.0` -g -Wall -O0 -c cli.c
gcc -o httpget cli.o `pkg-config --libs glib-2.0`
```